# How to remove git remote branches locally which has been deleted online?

Tags: git, github, gitlab, git-branch, git-flow

After a successful merge request , the branch get's deleted on the gitlab but it still exist on my local machine so how can I remove that branch locally ?

[image]

How can I remove config-tailwind branch locally only ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can fetch with `--prune` so that deleted remote branches disappear on the local repository

```
git fetch --prune -a
```

Comment: Didn't work for me. I had to use `git remote prune <remote name, e.g. origin>`.